# Programatically extract content of PowerPoint slides into MS Word-like format?

Tags: vba, vbscript, powerpoint, extract

I'd like to extract all of the information (formatted text, images, etc) from [powerpoint](/questions/tagged/powerpoint) slides into a flowing, readable (MS Word-style) format.

I'm not interested in keeping the slide concept at all--think of taking class slides from a college course and batch converting them all into one collective study guide.

1. I can't find a way to do this *within* [powerpoint](/questions/tagged/powerpoint) (though if you know of one, please share!) and,
2. I don't have experience scripting Office apps. Is this kind of thing easily done? Does this kind of script already exist somewhere?

***Clarification***:
 In an earlier version of this post, I used the word "flowing" to refer to a *slide-free* (MS Word-like) format. This does not, however, refer to the actual formatting of slide content.  So keeping bullet lists, etc. is fine and even desirable.

Comment: You still could be clearer as to what you want. For example do you require this to a `vbscript` applicable to any ppt file? Are you ok with doing it manually via the menus as some of the current answer suggest

Comment: The code [here](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00274_Export_Text_to_a_text_file-_extract_text_from_PowerPoint_-Mac_or_PC-.htm) will dump text and distinguish between title, subtitle, body and other text. It is a more detailed code version than the one posted by Steve Rindberg below

Answer (score 2):

I don't see this being a simple task. College professors use a format of either "TITLE: BULLET POINTS OR IMAGE" or "EVERY WORD I'M ABOUT TO SAY" for their slides in my experience, and you're just not going to get flowing, readable text from the former no matter what you do. For the latter, you've already got your text, you just have to copy it to another document.

I think you might as well just open the PowerPoint, select all the text, and copy+paste into Word/Publisher/InDesign/your favorite page layout program. You'll have the same effect and the same amount of editing after the fact except without all the hassle of writing a program to do it for you.

Doing a Print operation to a PDF with the N-up options might be a good solution for handouts if that's all you need. You could expand the idea and condense ALL the slide decks into one, get it printed (with N slides per page and the note space next to it) and bound, and voila, instant study guide. I've seen that, and then you get options for note taking.

More power to you if you're doing this just because you can - don't let me stop you. There is much good learning to be had that way. You might want to look into writing a program using the Microsoft.Office.Interop namespace in .NET (starting at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772069.aspx ), or perhaps look on CPAN ( http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=all&query=powerpoint ) and do it with Perl! There are lots of ways to do it, but you've got to be up for the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Text is fairly simple to extract, but what text do you want?  The text from the title and body text placeholders only?  File, Save As, and choose to save the outline.

The other text on the slide?  That can be pulled out to a text file programmatically, but in what order?  Suppose you have a complex diagram with text callouts.  Extracting the text is going to give you gibberish.  There's no obvious/meaningful order to the text other than what the human viewer supplies by noting that "Ah.  The arrow next to this bit of text points to the fribulator sub-assembly, so must relate to it in some way."  Try doing that in code. ;-)

You could give the author a way to sort the text into reading order so that the code knows what order to extract it in, but that would require a fair amount of work on the part of the author.

If you can be certain that all of the content is in title+bullet form, no worries.  Otherwise, you'd have to be able to articulate exactly what you want extracted, in what form and in what order before you could get anywhere with this.

Comment: In that case, have a look at this and the subsequent pages: Export Slide Number and Title Text to a text file
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00332_Export_Slide_Number_and_Title_Text_to_a_text_file.htm

Answer (score 1):

MS Word-style is not only readable, but writeable as well (which was not specified in your requirements). If you want a read-only guide, PDF is your natural choice (either through Acrobat Distiller or LibreOffice). Combine individual Acrobatted presentations with PDFtk, or Acrobat or Foxit and you're good to go without any programming at all.

"Is this kind of thing easily done?" - Yes, your humble servant did a couple of similar scripts ages ago (extracting enhanced metafiles from Powerpoint slides).

"Does this kind of script already exist somewhere?" - Yes. Probably at hundreds of places, but not sure if any of them get posted to the 'Net. All things considered think you'd be better off learning some scripting and macro programming on your own, since a ready-made script may be not quite fit for your needs - and to understand and rewrite it you'd need more time than to code & debug from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention that title+bullet form is ok, open the file, choose to save as and pick Outline as the save-as type.

Comment: But would this preserve "all of the information (formatted text, images, etc)"?

Comment: No, just the text.  Sorry ... got distracted by title+bullet and lost track of the images requirement in your original query. Have you tried the various Send to Word options, though?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could parse through the PowerPoint file for formatting, text and pictures. There are Visual Studio namespaces available for such a task. You open the file, parse through it and make Word file from these. Complicated work, as you would have to consider type of elements and their position, you would have to use a temporary structure for each slide.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this sample code :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278331.aspx

**How to: Get All the Text in All Slides in a Presentation**

Basically, using c# and openXML SDK 2.0, it loops through all the slides in the presentation, and then adds each text in every slide into a string builder. You can write out the result into a text file if you like (modification required).

**Recommendation: <25 oct 2012>**

For your study guide, maybe you could extract all the text in each slide, and dump those text programmatically (by adding that function into the sample code above while it's iterating the slides) into the "Notes" section of each slide. With that, you can print it in Notes Page view. You'll get the entire slide image at the top half of the page, and the actual slide texts at the bottom of it in the Notes Page view. It sure beats trying to copy and paste all the text from the slide into the notes section. You can even print it 2 slides per page, as small text would not be an issue inside the slide's image, and diagrams would still be visible more or less.

Unfortunatly, this method works for simple standard slide format ... meaning, it's OK if your slides just have a title, and a center text box with all the bullet points... any complex slide layout (maybe text boxes scattered everywhere) will come out in non-order and will be confusing. But at least you can still look at the slide image above to make sense of it :)

Comment: would this preserve "all of the information (formatted text, images, etc)"?

Comment: no it would not preserve the formatted text and images unfortunately. this sample code gives you a list of <string> at the end of each day for each slide. Although you can technically preserve the formatting and also get the images ... a lot of code is required to expand on the example above. I recommended something on the original answer above. ^